# jQuery: Keep submenu open while hovering over submenu items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This has been asked a lot. But I can't seem to find a solution that works. I have a jQuery code that opens my submenu on hover, but it vanishes after I try to go over the submenu items. How can I fix that?

Here's my code:

```js
$('.hover').hover(
  function() {
    $('.drop-box').show();
  },
  function() {
    $('.drop-box').hide();
  })
});
```

```css
.drop-box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: darkgreen;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hover">hover</div>
  <div class="drop-box">
    <div class="container row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p class="mb-0">Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p class="mb-0">Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p class="mb-0">Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place `.drop-box` and all its contents inside `.hover`.
Plus, you need to remove the `top` property to prevent the gap between the text and the `.drop-box`.

```js
$('.hover').hover(
                function () {
                    $('.drop-box').show();
                },
                function () {
                    $('.drop-box').hide();
                }
            );
```

```css
.drop-box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: darkgreen;
    // top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hover">hover<div class="drop-box">
    <div class="container row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p class="mb-0">Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p class="mb-0">Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p class="mb-0">Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

**UPDATE:**

If you can't move `.drop-box` into `.hover`, you can wrap everything with a div and add the hover event using CSS:

```css
.drop-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: darkgreen;
  // top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.everything:hover .drop-box {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="everything">
  <div class="hover">hover</div>
  <div class="drop-box">
    <div class="container row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p class="mb-0">Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p class="mb-0">Text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p class="mb-0">Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, but what if I can't place it inside .hover? Could I still make it work, somehow?

Comment: Well, there's a CSS solution that can be much simpler than jQuery. Is it okay?

Comment: Is it possible to wrap the divs with another div?

Comment: Great! I wrapped everything with an `.everything` div. Check out this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zanp2zfj/). My CSS solution is at the bottom of the CSS section.

Comment: looks like JSFiddle's bug. Remove the comment I added and it'll work. [An updated Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/zanp2zfj/2/).

Comment: Yup, awesome! Thank you so much! It works! Could you update your answer please, so I can accept it as correct one? :)